# How do I get rid of black bar in python window?

Tags: python, opencv, winapi, screen-capture

I'm working on a Object Detection project for the game Cuphead using OpenCV and Python. Now I'm trying to capture objects in real time but when the detection window displays I get this rare black bar on the top and I don't know how to get rid of it, [here's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7re8E.jpg), on the left my object detection window and in the right the Cuphead game window.

Here's the code for the class used for this:

```
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con

class WindowCapture:

    # define monitor's width and height
    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        
        if window_name is None: # if we don't pass any window names capture desktop
            self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        else:
            # Find the game window
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            if not self.hwnd:
                raise Exception("Window not founnd: {}".format(window_name))

            # define window's widht and height. the resolution we'll work with
            window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
            self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
            self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

    def get_screenshot(self):
        

        # get the window image data
        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0,0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        # create the screenshot image that we want to return to be processed
        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        # Free Resources
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

        # get rid of the alpha channel in the img
        img = img[..., :3]
        img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

        return img
```

Comment: is this a problem caused by this `get_screenshot` thing? looks like the bounding box is the entire window, but it only captures the client area... -- just capture it all, then crop off what you don't need, with numpy slicing.

Comment: I think the problem might be in the constructor, when assigning the width and the height if I write the exact dimensions I'm working with (1176x664) the window displayed has this dimensions and also the bar, so I can't see the whole game window. But using this ```win32gui.GetWindowRect()``` function makes the window bigger so it displays all the game window plus the black bar

Comment: See [about windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows) to learn about the different regions that make up an application window. `GetWindowRect` returns a rectangle enclosing the entire window, though you probably only care about the client area.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll search there!

Answer (score 0):

It seems `img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)` causes the problem. As [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect#remarks) and @IInspectable said,

> In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area
> occupied by the drop shadow.